# How to zoom in a blueprint plan?

Tags: factorio

I just made one which extends on a very long distance (for an upload/unload train stations). Now, I'm trying to modify it by deleting some belts and other items, but it's really hard because the blueprint is totally zoom out.

Is there a way or a keybind to zoom in a blueprint (without mods)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to zoom within the blueprint editing GUI, as far as I know.

If you have a land area which is large enough to fit the blueprint, free of obstacles, and not covered by any roboports, you can place the blueprint, delete the relevant ghosts, then make a new blueprint from that.

(I have seen in the past some glitches where making a blueprint from not-fully-constructed things lost some information, in particular about modules, but I think none of those cases apply when *all* of the objects are still ghosts and they may have all been fixed.)